# Is it possible to deprecate implicit conversion while allowing explicit conversion?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Suppose I have a simple `Duration` class:

```
class Duration
{
    int seconds;
public:
    Duration(int t_seconds) : seconds(t_seconds) { }
};

int main()
{
    Duration t(30);
    t = 60;
}
```

And I decide that I don't like being able to implicitly convert from `int` to `Duration`. I can make the constructor `explicit`:

```
class Duration
{
    int seconds;
public:
    explicit Duration(int t_seconds) : seconds(t_seconds) { }
};

int main()
{
    Duration t(30); // This is fine, conversion is explicit
    t = 60; // Doesn't compile: implicit conversion no longer present for operator=
}
```

But what if I don't want to immediately break all calling code that's implicitly converting to `Duration`? What I would like to have is something like:

```
class Duration
{
    int seconds;
public:
    [[deprecated]]
    Duration(int t_seconds) : seconds(t_seconds) { }

    explicit Duration(int t_seconds) : seconds(t_seconds) { }
};

int main()
{
    Duration t(30); // Compiles, no warnings, uses explicit constructor
    t = 60; // Compiles but emits a deprecation warning because it uses implicit conversion
}
```

This would allow existing code to compile while identifying any places that currently rely on implicit conversion, so they can either be rewritten to use explicit conversion if it's intended or rewritten to have correct behavior if not.

However this is impossible because I can't overload `Duration::Duration(int)` with `Duration::Duration(int)`.

Is there a way to achieve something like this effect short of "Make the conversion explicit, accept that calling code won't compile until you've written the appropriate changes"?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to turn on a compiler warning for implicit conversions? `-Wconversion` in gcc for example.

Comment: That doesn't actually appear to [emit a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/9G1dzqcvc) for this situation. Something along those lines would probably suffice, though.

Comment: You might do it with conditional compilation, #ifdef REFACTOR explicit Duration(int) #else Duration(int). Then compile project by project and define REFACTOR (commandline) test the code. Once you've done all the projects remove the ifdef and all the defines (or the other way around start with a define on all projects and remove it one by one)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can turn `Duration(int t_seconds)` into a template function that can accept an `int` and set it to deprecated.

```
#include<concepts>

class Duration {
  int seconds;
public:
  template<std::same_as<int> T>
  [[deprecated("uses implicit conversion")]]
  Duration(T t_seconds) : Duration(t_seconds) { }
  
  explicit Duration(int t_seconds) : seconds(t_seconds) { }
};
```

If you allow `t = 0.6`, just change the `same_as` to `convertible_to`.

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/a77v4bETG)

Comment: God that looks so clean. I was trying to weird SFINAE with c++17 and couldn't get it.

Comment: The SFINAE version doesn't seem [that bad](https://godbolt.org/z/3TnP31rh7) once this gave me the idea to try it. Great suggestion!

Comment: Downgrade to [C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/aoofo85sY) and [C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/EbE949nxc).

Comment: what does this line `std::same_as<int> T` do? From cppreference `std::same_as` takes two arguments. Can someone explain what does `std::same_as<int> T` do.

Comment: @TheScore he uses C++20 concepts here, that is why I've provided downgraded versions.

Comment: @TheScore It's using it as a [constraint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Concepts). It's saying that `std::same_as<T, int>` must be satisfied for `T` to be a valid argument.

Comment: From that link: "In a type-constraint, a concept takes one less template argument than its parameter list demands, because the contextually deduced type is implicitly used as the first argument of the concept."

Comment: Note that this solution will break code like this: `Duration minute() { return {60}; }` The reason is that in copy-list-initialization, the overload resolution is done without considering `explicit`ness, and then the program is ill-formed if an explicit constructor actually gets selected.

Comment: Even just `template<typename = void> [[deprecated]] Duration(int t_seconds) : Duraction(t_seconds) {}` works, since an explicit initialization would always pick the non-template one

Comment: @BrianBi • but in this case — transitioning to `explicit` — that's probably okay and the first thing to get cleaned up.